# this mod_rewrite rule has me for a loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to have `/path/short` serve up the content held by the file `/path/short.html`, but if the user types `/path/short.html` or `/path/short/` I want him to be redirected (with 301) to `/path/short`. This is what I have so far in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/path/handle.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/short(.html|/)?$
RewriteRule ^(.+) /cgi-bin/handle\.cgi?$1 [PT,QSA]

RewriteRule ^path$ /path/short.html

#-------
RewriteRule ^short/$ /path/short [R=301,L]
# RewriteRule ^short.html$ /path/short [R=301,L]
```

The rules reflect the fact that `handle.cgi` will receive all other requests (ie, `/path/this`, `/path/`, `/path/somethingelse`, etc.) which is working great. So far, the `/path/short/` redirects correctly to `/path/short` and `/path/short` is properly showing the content in `/path/short.html`, however, uncommenting the last line causes a loop. So, how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend pointed me towards another question which helped me arrive at this solution:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ads/short(.html|/)?$
RewriteRule ^(.+) /cgi-bin/handle\.cgi?$1 [PT,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^short(.html|/)$ /ads/short [R=301]
RewriteRule ^short$ /ads/short.html
```

which works perfectly.

Comment: Also, while testing, make sure you use [R] instead of [R=301], browsers heavily cache 301 redirects, while not so with 302's (the redirect used when it is just R), so you might be seeing cached results instead of what should be yielded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in `/path/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /path/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(short)(/|\.html) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(short)/?$ $1.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, unfortunately these give me a 404 error, and I found an alternative answer which works perfectly for my use case. Thanks again.

Comment: This is tested code and worked in my testing. Also your proposed rule doesn't redirect `/path/short/`

Comment: your code didn't work for me, whereas the ruleset I wrote as my answer did. Are you sure you tried it with the original code too? Ie, I can't have it conflict with the first part.

Comment: These rules are supposed to replace all of your rules. You need to keep your htaccess as I showed here in my answer and then test and let me know which URL isn't working for you.

Comment: hi, as mentioned, replacing all the rules would make the handler not work. Also, the NC flag would cause things like SHORT.HTML to be redirected, which I do not want. However, using the basic principles of the rules you included I was able to derive another solution which also works, so thanks for your input.

Comment: You could have just taken out `NC` from this. Also `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /path/short.html` is redundant in your rule.